# Is there a way to make the view called when UIImagePickerController.allowsEditing = true have a circle instead of square?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to implement a way to allow a user to quickly edit which portion of their selected photo to be an icon. However the default state is simply a square but my icons are circles. I know I can simply make a circle from the square image they select but from a UX standpoint that's not ideal. I would prefer them to simply select an image with knowledge of it being a circle in mind.

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want a circular imagePicker?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to easily do this. I would suggest keeping it as a square and simply displaying the image in a round imageView.

There should be no significant difference between saving the image as a circle and displaying it as a circle.

Hope this helps.